# sql script cover all possible variable combinations? help, app, somthing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, testing

I'm sure somebody will know of a app or some website to help do this:

I need to run a script in the 'database engine tuning advisor', but would like to do all or most of the possible combinations of variables for my select statement/function.

For example, I have:

@RegionID, can be any value from SELECT EntityGroup.Id FROM EntityGroup (e.g. 1,2,3,4)
@LanguageId, can be any value from SELECT Language.Id (e.g. en-GB, tr-TR)
@Group1, can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

and so on.

then to have something generate an sql script such as

```
SELECT * From xyz (1, 'en-GB', 1)
SELECT * From xyz (1, 'tr-TR', 1)
SELECT * From xyz (2, 'en-GB', 1)
SELECT * From xyz (2, 'tr-TR', 1)
```

over and over with each of the possible combinations of variables.

Any tips?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this query:

```
SELECT  'SELECT * FROM xyz (' + CAST(A.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', ''' + 
        B.Id + ''', ' + CAST(C.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' AS Script
FROM EntityGroup A
CROSS JOIN [Language] B
CROSS JOIN [Group] C
```

And then copy the results to get your script. (Though you need to know that if there are more than just those values on the tables, the `CROSS JOIN` will rapidly grow in size).

Comment: That's great... And I can union to limit some things like this unless you know a better way?

Comment: SELECT  'SELECT * FROM xyz (' + CAST(A.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', ''' + 
        B.Id + ''', ' + CAST(C.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' AS Script
FROM EntityGroup A
CROSS JOIN (Select 'en-GB' as id UNION select 'tr-TR' as id) B
CROSS JOIN (Select '1' as id UNION select '2' as id UNION select '3' as id UNION select '4' as id)  C